# toilet tank not filling

Tags: toilet

Toilet flushes ok, but then to fill tank, shut off valve has to be turned off and then back on. Why?

Comment: If you can access the fill valve, leave the shut off valve ON when it is *supposed* to be filling, and manually manipulate the float mechanism on the fill valve. What happens? And can you take the lid off the tank and post a pic of the fill valve; and a pic of the shut off valve?

Answer (score 1):

Your toilet fill valve has failed. You probably will need to replace it.

Whether it can be cleaned and rinsed out or adjusted or repaired, or must be replaced, depends on the type of fill valve. There are over a dozen common styes. Do a net search for "toilet fill valve images" and you will see what I mean.

You will also find the picture that matches your valve, which will lead you to the manufacturer, which will probably lead you to a tutorial on what you can do to maintain it. I can't tell you exactly what to do unless you post a picture of your fill valve.

The reason I think you will probably need to replace it is, locking up until the main water pressure is removed is a strange failure mode for a fill valve. However if your fill valve is a type that can be cleaned or adjusted, try that first (if you can find out how to take it apart).

Don't forget to close the supply valve before working on it, and if you have to temporarily open the supply valve to flush the line or whatever, hold a heavy towel or rag over the partially disassembled fill valve to avoid spraying the room.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the problem is in the in tank fill valve, but there is the possibility that your flexible supply line is not a simple line but instead has a flood safe valve in it and this is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

Your toilet valve seals are sticking, probably from age and they are deteriorating. Easiest fix is to replace the toilet valve. They are inexpensive and trying to get replacement parts could be a challenge.